# How to write methods with named parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method defined below.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayReadOnlyGrid(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string containerId, 
    MvcHtmlString innerHtml)
{
    try
    {
        var outerDiv = new TagBuilder("DIV");
        outerDiv.AddCssClass("ML5 MT5 MR5");
        outerDiv.MergeAttribute("id", containerId);
        if (innerHtml != null && !innerHtml.Equals(string.Empty))
        {
            outerDiv.InnerHtml = innerHtml.ToString();
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(outerDiv.ToString());
    }
    catch 
    {                
        throw;
    }
}
```

When I'm calling this method I need the format like below:

```
DisplayReadOnlyGrid(containerId="mycontainerid", innerHtml="innerhtml")
```

How can I do that?

Comment: [Try the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
html.DisplayReadOnlyGrid(containerId: "mycontainerid", innerHtml: "innerhtml");
```

You can pass the parameters in any order, and you can pass both positional and named parameters, however the named parameters must follow the positional parameters for obvious reasons.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since C# 4.0 this works out of the box, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). There is nothing you have to do to enable it.
However, please note that the correct syntax uses a colon, not the equals sign:

```
helper.DisplayReadOnlyGrid(containerId: "mycontainerid", innerHtml: "innerhtml");
```

If you are using an older version, you are not able to do that at all.

Comment: If they have a newer version of the compiler.

Comment: @JOTHI: What don't you understand?

Comment: @JOTHI: You didn't read my answer, did you? As I wrote: You don't have to do anything. This just works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

The format for using named arguments is as follows:

```
helper.DisplayReadOnlyGrid(containerId: "mycontainerid", innerHtml: "innerhtml");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation for the method**:

First its an [**extension method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). Which is notable with the key word `this` in the parameters. To be precise its an extension method on `HtmlHelper`

Second the parameters: They are [**Named parameters**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)(feature of C# 4.0) and you can call that method:

```
helper.DisplayReadOnlyGrid(containerId:"mycontainerid", innerHtml:"innerhtml")
```

Named parameters allow you to specify parameters in any order and are helpful with default parameters as well, which is also a new feature in C# 4.0